# Issues with Case Business Process Picklist values while using Ant

Tags: deployment, picklist, error, ant

Were doing a first time deploy of code to a QA box and for some reason I keep getting errors about Picklist values not present. I can see them in the Case object under the BusinessProcess section, where the value is one of the members. The field in question is Status, which in the object file doesn't have any values, I guess only the BusinessProcess does..? I've tried adding CustomField and BusinessProcess to the package.xml but it looks like it all goes into the Object file. Not sure why the values are present in the file, yet Ant keeps saying theres no picklist values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexTrigger</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>AuthProvider</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Case.Moral Character Application</members>
    <members>Case.Testing Accommodation Process</members>
    <members>Case.Request Process</members>
    <members>Case.Evaluation Request Process</members>
    <members>Case.CBX%2FFYLSX Application</members>
    <members>Case.Legal Spec</members>
    <members>Case.Registration Application</members>
    <members>Case.SBC Standard</members>
    <members>Case.Test Center%2FMethod Change Request</members>
    <name>BusinessProcess</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CompactLayout</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.Type</members>
    <members>Case.Type</members>
    <members>Case.Reason</members>
    <members>Case.Status</members>
    <members>Contact.Applicant_Type__c</members>
    <members>Event.Calendar__c</members>
    <members>Task.Calendar__c</members>
    <members>SDOC__SDRelationship__c.Applicant_History__c</members>
    <members>User.Contact_s_Account_ID__c</members>
    <members>User.Social_Security_Number__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>Case</members>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <members>Contract</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Applicant_Community</members>
    <name>CustomSite</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ExternalDataSource</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>CBX_Subjects</members>
    <members>Countries</members>
    <members>LS_Specialties</members>
    <members>Months</members>
    <members>Proficiency_Level</members>
    <members>Rating_1_through_5</members>
    <members>US_States</members>
    <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Group</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Applicant Community</members>
    <name>Network</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Applicant Community User.profile</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Queue</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.Sports_Organization</members>
    <members>Account.Business_Organization</members>
    <members>Account.University_Department</members>
    <members>Account.HH_Account</members>
    <members>Account.Administrative</members>
    <members>Account.Academic_Program</members>
    <members>Account.Educational_Institution</members>
    <members>Account.Jurisdiction</members>
    <members>Case.SBC_Registration_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Legal_Specialization_Retirement_Request</members>
    <members>Case.Legal_Specialization_Recertification_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Legal_Specialization_Examination_Application</members>
    <members>Case.General_Request</members>
    <members>Case.Wall_Certificate_Request</members>
    <members>Case.SSN_Update_Request</members>
    <members>Case.Name_Change_Request</members>
    <members>Case.Educational_Standards</members>
    <members>Case.Multijurisdictional_Practice_Application</members>
    <members>Case.California_Bar_Examination_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Test_Center_Method_Change_Request</members>
    <members>Case.First_Year_Law_Students_Examination_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Moral_Character_Determination_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Pro_Hac_Vice_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Foreign_Legal_Consultant_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Foreign_Legal_Consultant_Renewal_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Out_of_State_Attorney_Arbitration_Counsel_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Practical_Training_of_Law_Students_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Pre_Legal_Evaluation_Request</members>
    <members>Case.Law_Office_Study_Session_Report</members>
    <members>Case.Legal_Evaluation_Request</members>
    <members>Case.Multijurisdictional_Practice_Renewal_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Legal_Specialization_Certification_Application</members>
    <members>Case.Testing_Accommodation_Request</members>
    <members>Case.Moral_Character_Extension_Application</members>
    <members>Contact.Contractor_Provider</members>
    <members>Contact.Law_School_Official</members>
    <members>Contact.Attorney_Applicant</members>
    <members>Contact.Legal_Specialist</members>
    <members>Contact.General_Applicant</members>
    <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Role</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Applicant_Community_C</members>
    <name>SiteDotCom</name>
</types>

<version>43.0</version>
```

edit: updated with package.xml. this has been through many iterations, sometimes calling out more fields, or more objects, and many mixes of things. at this point i just need to get things working so im brute forcing whatever i can and manually updating data as needed

Comment: Can you try manually edit the Case object metadata with Case status ? <fields><fullName>Status</fullName><picklist><picklistValues><fullName>Closed</fullName><default>false</default><closed>true</closed></picklistValues> </picklist></fields>

Comment: tihs isnt something i really want to do for every picklist field, record type, and business process. id rather call them out in their respective types and let the migration tool do that

Comment: Can you provide your package.xml portion for the custom fields ?